# React component receiveing props as undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I build a project for a school’s records system, in which I build the front-end with React. On the main component of the admin page, I wanted to have a react-router which will navigate through the admin dialogs. As I tried to implement this, the following problem occurred: when trying to pass parameters to a class through the react route component, the child component receives no props.

I have the following react component hierarchy:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
       super();

       console.log("in class: " + this.props)
   }

   render() { return <div>test</div>}
}

class AdminPage extends BasicPage {
    /* Other class functions here... */
    render() {
       let pageBody = "";
       if(!this.state.isLoading)
           pageBody = (
               <Router>
                   <Switch>
                       <Route path={"/:schoolName/admin"} component={AdminMenu} exact/>
                       <Route path={"/:schoolName/admin/view/:id"} exact
                          component={() => <Test par1="abc" />} />
                   </Switch>
               </Router>
           );
       return (
           <Layout title={ this.state.isLoading ?
               TITLE_UNTIL_LOADED :
               PAGE_TITLE + this.state.schoolPrefs.heb_name}
                   subtitle={ this.state.subtitle }
                   notification={ this.state.notification }
                   isLoading={ this.state.isLoading }
           >
               {pageBody}
           </Layout>
       );
    }
}
```

When I go to `/Random Name/admin/view/someID`, it prints to the console `in class: undefined`.

I then wanted to see if the problem is in the passing component or the receiving one. I defined the function `otherTest(props)` as follows:

```
function otherTest(props) {
   console.log("Function props: " + props);
   return (<Test {...props} />);
}
```

And then changed the route component like so:

```
<Route path={"/:schoolName/admin/view/:id"} exact
  component={otherTest} />
```

When then I went to `/Random Name/admin/view/someID`, I saw that the function received the props just fine, but the log within `<Test … />` still printed `undefined`.

I also tried adding `<Test param1=”123” />` after the `{pageBody}` variable in the main render function, but it printed `in class: undefined` as well.

Does someone know where the problem might be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must take props parameter from constructor and then pass it to super.

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use this.props in constructor beacuse constructor fire only at the creating class moment. 
Use this code:

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);

 console.log(props);
}
```